# Passing php variable argument to onclink function through python script

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

I have been trying to call a onclick js function which contains a an argument in the form of PHP variable. My code looks something like this:

```
    echo "<input type = 'button' onclick = 'activateit(".json_encode($name).")' value = '$name'>";
```

But it gives the following error:

```
    activateit is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick
```

And the chrome inspect element shows it like this:

```
     onclick = 'activateit("chai")'
```

where $name = chai. I have been stuck on this for quite some time now. Please help.

Comment: `activateit is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick` simply means that it is not recognizing your `activateit` function declaration

Comment: i would say to give an `id` to your input and then handle the process using `eventlistener` it's more cleaner and more effective

Comment: the thing is i can only call the activateit() function from within the php code only because i the value $name is taken from a table and there is a loop which is iterating over the whole table....and @CAllen the cause i think is the variable argument but i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: I had just gotten that error the day before yesterday on a program for my friend and what fixed it for me was that his function name was `getData ()` and he had `getdata` in his html code the same way you have yours. So you should also check that. Appearently its case sensitive. But I agree with Amr Aly, what I would do is assign an id to he button and use a click event instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments use the below to make things better you would assign your value to id or any attribute you want to call it and for each button added you use the class attribute so that you can have multiple buttons added without any problems and also to avoid having many click event declarations. Ofcoarse you would have to include your jquery script tag as well

```
// echo "<input type = 'button' onclick = 'activateit(".json_encode($name).")' value = '$name'>"; is change to the below
echo "<input type = 'button' id=".json_encode($name)." value = '$name' class='added_button'>";
```

we then use `$ (document).on` because we want the event to be fired for any buttons that exists and also if there are more buttons added after the page loads

```
$ (document).on ('click', '.added_button', function (e) {
    // this will be added if you dont want a form to submit when the button is pressed if it is in a form
    // or to stop it from doing whatever it was meant to do
    e.preventDefault (); 

    var name = this.id; // this will give you the value 'chai'

    // to test it we do an alert 
    alert (name);


    // add your code here
});
```

to include jquery use `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>`